# Azure Webapp - Receiving 502 page error

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I have a web site deployed under App Services of Azure. It is working well up to couple of days before. But since two days Iam receiving below error

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. 
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.
```

When I access Site with xyz.azurewebsites.net it doesn't show this error. This is only displayed when I access with custom domain name. I have enabled Failure Request Tracing, but FREB logs doesn't show any 502 errors.

Can anyone help me understand what's the issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Azure WebApps have ARR sever (aka the FrontEnd) in front of the actual machines serving the web applications (known as the workers) and HTTP 502 is returned via the FrontEnd servers typically under these conditions

1. The request is taking a really long time on the actual worker
   machine to execute
2. The worker process corresponding to the web
   application is not even running or crashing multiple times.

Since the HTTP 502 error is happening on the FrontEnd servers, you won’t see these in the IIS logs because the IIS logs are of the worker so basically in your case either the request is taking too long to execute or the worker process serving the request (on the actual worker machine) is crashing.
As you mentioned that things work when you access the site over a custom domain vs xyz.azurewebsites.net then I would suggest checking a few things.

1. **Make sure that your custom domain is really resolving to the right xyz.azurewebsites.net**. Try using www.digwebinterface.com and put your custom domain there and make sure that it resolves to xyz.azurewebsites.net
2. Check if by any chance your code does something special for requests which arrive on your custom domain. Meaning any special processing like database lookups, or URLRewrite rules getting triggered etc. for requests only to custom domains.
3. Also check in your FREB logs to see if you can spot any long running requests when the hostname contains custom domain. You can use the FREB Viewer under the Support Portal for your WebApp to check this easily
4. Check if the WebApp is crashing by going to the EventViewer under the Support Portal for your WebApp and see if there are any crash related events.

You can reach the support portal of your WebApp by going to https://xyz.scm.azurewebsites.net/Support (where xyz is name of your Azure WebApp)
If this doesn’t help, then I recommend engaging Microsoft Support as they can check some of these things easily at their end.